# Encountering ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0) with Celery in Django project on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have been working on a Django project on my Windows 7 machine, using VS-Code as my development environment. Recently, I decided to incorporate Celery for handling asynchronous tasks. However, I have been encountering a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0) whenever I try to retrieve the result of a task.

Here's a snippet of how I am creating and calling the task:

```
# common/test_tasks.py
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# In Django shell
from common.test_tasks import add
result = add.delay(4, 6)
print(result.ready())  # Outputs: True
print(result.get())  # Raises ValueError
```

I have tried different Celery configurations and also different backends and brokers. Initially, I was using Redis as both the broker and backend, but I encountered the same error. I switched the broker to RabbitMQ (pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost//) while keeping Redis for the result backend. Still, the error persists. I also attempted to downgrade Celery to version 3.1.24 but faced installation issues on Windows.

Here are my relevant settings in the settings.py file:

```
# settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

I've also checked the logs, but nothing stood out. The tasks seem to be executing successfully, but the error occurs when trying to fetch the result.

Additionally, I've scoured through multiple forums and documentation but haven't found a solution that works for my specific setup. Any insights or suggestions on how I might resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you try to unpack a variable that does not hold any value. Which means, the variable you are unpacking does not store anything in it while unpacking. You need to make sure that a value is passed to it before unpacking. Also make sure whether the size is matching or not. Unmatched size and lacking value can be the leading causes.